# virtualbox bridged networking requires ip protocol on windows host

Tags: virtualbox

So here is the challenge, take one computer (named host) running windows with virtualbox and more than one network card and the same number of administratively separated subnets. Add a policy requirement that the windows box must have an ip address on one and only one subnet and that the guest must have an ip address, but it must not be on the subnet that the host is on. bridged networking is prefered as running vpn to the guest across the host's network is real overkill given that the wire is right there.

The naive solution (does not work) would be to configure an ip address on the first network card (static or dhcp as normal) and disable the ip binding on the second network card. Then when configuring the virtual machine, to select bridged networking and the second network adaptor. This utterly fails as bridged networking only lists network cards that are bound to ip (either 4 or 6, both also works fine, it may work with ipx or netbeui but they are not available for recent versions of windows).

A workaround is to enable an ip protocol on the second adaptor and misconfigure it so that the address it uses is on a subnet that is not reachable, but the second shift sysop keeps trying to fix it.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Is Windows required on the host? This has a [pretty easy solution](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough) on a Linux host.

Comment: Indeed, on linux it is trivial, as you don't have to configure addresses on an adaptor at all, and can still use it without resorting to pci passthrough (which allows multiple virtual machines to share the adaptor, also a requirement) and better routing solutions offer additional options like proxy arp and ppp, and more. Alas, the spare processing power is on a windows box.